# PyQt run time issue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I want my code to run by showing the qtwidget and then running the forloop,
but it runs the forloop then shows my widget to me. Why is this?

```
class tes(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(tes, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        for i in range (1000000):
            print("s")

    def initUI(self):
        t = QTableWidget(8,8,self)        
        self.show()
        self.resize(1000,1000)
        t.setGeometry(0,0,500,500)
        t.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = tes()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's because the "showing" occurs in the `app.exec_()` line (i.e. when the mainloop starts). I guess you need to clarify what you are _really_ trying to do.

Answer (score 14):

Add [`QApplication.processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) before loop. Your widget will be shown, but unresponsive. To make application responsive, add `processEvents()` calls to some steps of your loop.

Example:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(tes, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()
    QApplication.processEvents()
    for i in range (1000000):
        if not i % 3:  # let application process events each 3 steps.
            QApplication.processEvents()
        print("s")
```

Comment: More specifically, when you call `self.initUI()`, the events being generated (such as showEvent) are being queued up into the event queue, yet the event loop has not yet started. When you call `processEvents()`, you are forcing it to flush out the queue manually.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me getting control over the GUI back. But now I don't know how to continue the thread I am switching to the GUI from?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you run `app.exec_()` after the for loop executes during the `tes` object initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The widget is only shown once the application is running, not when its initialised.  What exactly are you trying to do in the loop?  It might be better to connect it to a signal or handle it in an event, but it all depends what you're trying to acheive.