# RealTime output from a subprogram to a pyQT4 Widget

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm trying to redirect the stdout from a subprogram to the QTextBrowser widget. (Python 2.7, Window 7, pyQT4)

This is the sub program, it will be in an executable file:

```
#test.py
import time

print ("ABC")
time.sleep(1)
print ("DEF")
time.sleep(1)
print ("GHI")
time.sleep(1)
print ("JKL")
```

My pyQT4 program:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import subprocess, time, os, sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
class GUI (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ...
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        grid.addWidget (self.edit, 7, 0, 5, 7)

    def run(self):
        p = Popen (['C:\\...\\test.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        while True:
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            self.append_edit('>>>' + line)

    def append_edit(self, string):
        self.edit.append(string)
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    upgrade = GUI()
    sys.exit (app.exec_())
```

The program I have above will wait until the subprogram finish running then print everything into the widget. What I want is for the program to output `ABC` then `DEF` so on with one second in between into the widget WHILE the subprogram is running.

Edit: I can have the subprocess output to cmd just fine, however, if I were print it into the QTextBrowser, it will not work.

I have seen many questions about this issue, but none of them seems to answer my question.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm still new to python. I think this is maybe the problem:  **Fixed by adding** `QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()`

```
def initUI(self):
    ...
    running = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
    running.clicked.connect(self.run)
def run(self):
    time.sleep(1)
    append_edit('Before')
    time.sleep(2)
    append_edit('After')
```

So when I hit run in my program, instead of printing out Before first then wait 1 sec, it wait 3 seconds in total then print both Before and After. What cause this problem?

**Edit:** Even with `QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()` in my code, I'm still having the same issue. it will run the whole subprogram before showing the output to QTextBrowser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyQt run time issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622021/pyqt-run-time-issue)

Comment: Unfortunately the run time issue was another bug in my program, but the subprocess still having the same issue

Comment: Where are you adding the `processEvents` call?

Comment: after `Popen`, `p.stdout.readline()`, and `self.append_edit('>>>' + line)`

Comment: I'm suprised that the output exceeds "ABC". My understanding is that your endless loops readline first returns "ABC" then "" and break as the pipe should be empty at that moment.