# Python progressbar for download with PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, progress-bar

I wrote a little gui with PyQT where I want to connect a progressbar with the current download.

```
    with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
        start = time.clock()
        response = requests.get(content['location'], stream=True)
        total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')
        print(total_length)
        if total_length is None:
            f.write(response.content)
        else:
            for data in response.iter_content(1024):
                dl += len(data)
                f.write(data)
                done = int(100 * dl / int(total_length))
                ui.progressBar.setProperty("value", done)
```

This works fine until I move the window. Then it says no response and freezes. After the download is finished it is working perfectly again.

I am new to python but I think I need something like a sub process running the download so it's not blocking the gui.

Comment: If the user should be able to use other GUI functionality while downloading, you should indeed use `QThread` or `QtConcurrent` or `QProcess`.

Comment: Threading is the ideal solution but if your program is simple enough you can just use [`processEvents`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622166/1470749).

Comment: I tried threading first, but it failed at some point. But with processEvents it runs great.